# Optimum algorithm to check various combinations of items when number of items is too large

Tags: r, rstudio, psych

I have a data frame which has 20 columns/items in it, and 593 rows (number of rows doesn't matter though) as shown below:
[image]

Using this the reliability of test is obtained as 0.94, with the help of alpha from psych package `psych::alpha`. The output also gives me the the new value of cronbach's alpha if I drop one of the items. However, I want to know how many items can I drop to retain an alpha of at least 0.8 I used a brute force approach for the purpose where I am creating the combination of all the items that exists in my data frame and check if their alpha is in the range (0.7,0.9). Is there a better way of doing this, as this is taking forever to run because number of items is too large to check for all the combination of items. Below is my current piece of code:

```
numberOfItems <- 20
for(i in 2:(2^numberOfItems)-1){
  # ignoring the first case i.e. i=1, as it doesn't represent any model
  # convert the value of i to binary, e.g. i=5 will give combination = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
  # using the binaryLogic package
  combination <- as.binary(i, n=numberOfItems) 
  model <- c()
  for(j in 1:length(combination)){
    # choose which columns to consider depending on the combination
    if(combination[j])
      model <- c(model, j)
  }
  itemsToUse <- itemResponses[, c(model)]
  #cat(model)
  if(length(model) > 13){
    alphaVal <- psych::alpha(itemsToUse)$total$raw_alpha
    if(alphaVal > 0.7 && alphaVal < 0.9){
      cat(alphaVal)
      print(model)
    }
  }
}
```

A sample output from this code is as follows:

> 0.8989831 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclPh.png)  4  5  7  8  9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
>
> 0.899768 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclPh.png)  4  5  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 18 19 20
>
> 0.899937 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclPh.png)  4  5  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 15 16 17 19 20
>
> 0.8980605 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclPh.png)  4  5  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 19 20

Here are the first 10 rows of data:

> dput(itemResponses)
> structure(list(CESD1 = c(1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), CESD2 = c(2,
> 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), CESD3 = c(0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0), CESD4 = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), CESD5 = c(0,
> 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0), CESD6 = c(0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0,
> 0, 0), CESD7 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), CESD8 = c(1,
> 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), CESD9 = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1,
> 0, 1), CESD10 = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), CESD11 = c(0,
> 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0), CESD12 = c(0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0,
> 0, 0), CESD13 = c(0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0), CESD14 = c(0,
> 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), CESD15 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
> 1, 0), CESD16 = c(0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), CESD17 = c(0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), CESD18 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 1), CESD19 = c(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), CESD20 = c(0,
> 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("CESD1", "CESD2", "CESD3",
> "CESD4", "CESD5", "CESD6", "CESD7", "CESD8", "CESD9", "CESD10",
> "CESD11", "CESD12", "CESD13", "CESD14", "CESD15", "CESD16", "CESD17",
> "CESD18", "CESD19", "CESD20"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",
> "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: I think, you can compute the discrimination index (correlation with row-sumscore) for each item (or some other related index, such as the INFIT). Then sequentially delete the item with the lowest index (if you want to drop as many as possible) and compute the new alpha, until alpha falls below .8.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say here. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: My suggestion comes from a psychometric point of view, rather than a programming point of view. In order to be able to efficiently elaborate, would you mind providing a reproducible example (including item response data) and the expected outcome.

Comment: I can provide data, but I am not sure how to send it here. Data consists of 20 columns each having values in the range [0,4] (doesn't matter though). Expected outcome is that how many items to keep in order to have a reliability of 0.8 (or any target number).

Comment: you can apply `dput` on (a reasonable subset of) your data, and post the result in an edit of your original post.

Comment: I updated the question with first ten rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to replace the computation of `alpha` with the so-called *discrimination* for each item from classical test theory (CTT). The discrimination is the correlation of the item score with a "true score" (which we would assume to be the row sum).

Let the data be

```
dat <-  structure(list(CESD1 = c(1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), CESD2 = c(2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                       CESD3 = c(0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CESD4 = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
                       CESD5 = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0), CESD6 = c(0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), 
                       CESD7 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), CESD8 = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                       CESD9 = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), CESD10 = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                       CESD11 = c(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0), CESD12 = c(0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), 
                       CESD13 = c(0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0), CESD14 = c(0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
                       CESD15 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), CESD16 = c(0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                       CESD17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), CESD18 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
                       CESD19 = c(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), CESD20 = c(0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                  .Names = c("CESD1", "CESD2", "CESD3", "CESD4", "CESD5", "CESD6", "CESD7", "CESD8", "CESD9", 
                             "CESD10", "CESD11", "CESD12", "CESD13", "CESD14", "CESD15", "CESD16", "CESD17", 
                             "CESD18", "CESD19", "CESD20"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

We compute (1) the discrimination and (2) the alpha coefficient.

```
stat <- t(sapply(1:ncol(dat), function(ii){
  dd <- dat[, ii]
  # discrimination is the correlation of the item to the rowsum
  disc <- if(var(dd, na.rm = TRUE) > 0) cor(dd, rowSums(dat[, -ii]), use = "pairwise")
  # alpha that would be obtained when we skip this item
  alpha <- psych::alpha(dat[, -ii])$total$raw_alpha
  c(disc, alpha)
  }))
dimnames(stat) <- list(colnames(dat), c("disc", "alpha^I"))
stat <- data.frame(stat)
```

Observe that the discrimination (which is more efficient to compute) is inversely proportional to `alpha` that is obtained when deleting this item. In other words, `alpha` is highest when there are many high "discriminating" items (that correlate with each other).

```
plot(stat, pch = 19)
```

[image]

Use this information to select the sequence with which the items should be deleted to fall below a benchmark (say .9, since the toy data doesn't allow for a lower mark):

**1)** delete as many items as possible to stay above the benchmark; that is, start with the least discriminating items.

```
stat <- stat[order(stat$disc), ]
this <- sapply(1:(nrow(stat)-2), function(ii){
  ind <- match(rownames(stat)[1:ii], colnames(dat))
  alpha <- psych::alpha(dat[, -ind, drop = FALSE])$total$raw_alpha
})

delete_these <- rownames(stat)[which(this > .9)]
psych::alpha(dat[, -match(delete_these, colnames(dat)), drop = FALSE])$total$raw_alpha
length(delete_these)
```

**2)** delete as few items as possible to stay above the benchmark; that is, start with the highest discriminating items.

```
stat <- stat[order(stat$disc, decreasing = TRUE), ]
this <- sapply(1:(nrow(stat)-2), function(ii){
  ind <- match(rownames(stat)[1:ii], colnames(dat))
  alpha <- psych::alpha(dat[, -ind, drop = FALSE])$total$raw_alpha
})

delete_these <- rownames(stat)[which(this > .9)]
psych::alpha(dat[, -match(delete_these, colnames(dat)), drop = FALSE])$total$raw_alpha
length(delete_these)
```

Note, that **1)** is coherent with classical item selection procedures in (psychological/educational) diagnostic/assessments: remove items from the assessment, that fall below a benchmark in terms of discriminatory power.

Comment: Let me go through it, it will take me sometime to digest what you have done. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as follows, now I am dropping a fixed number of items and changing the value of `numberOfItemsToDrop` from 1 to 20 manually. Although it is a lil better, but it still is taking too long to run :(

I hope there is some better way of doing this.

```
numberOfItemsToDrop <- 13
combinations <- combinat::combn(20, numberOfItemsToDrop)
timesToIterate <- length(combinations)/numberOfItemsToDrop
for(i in 1:timesToIterate){
  model <- combinations[,i]
  itemsToUse <- itemResponses[, -c(model)]
  alphaVal <- psych::alpha(itemsToUse)$total$raw_alpha
  if(alphaVal < 0.82){
    cat("Cronbach's alpha =",alphaVal, ", number of items dropped = ", length(model), " :: ")
    print(model)
  }
}
```